# Trying to replace 2011 with getFullYear in copyright div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace the year 2011 in a footer that contains the copyright with the current year.

Currently I have successfully replaced '2003-2011' with '2003-2012' like this:

```
  $(document).ready (function (function(){

 $('div.footer').html($('div.footer').html() .replace('2003-2011','2003-2012'));

});
```

But I wanted to replace '2011' with the current year so you don't have to change the script every year.

Doing this doesn't work:

```
 var year=getFullYear();


 $(document).ready (function(){


$('div.footer').html($('div.footer').html() .replace('2011','year'));



 });
```

As always, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `('div.footer').html($('div.footer').html().replace('2011', new Date().getFullYear()));`

Comment: If you have access to server-side code, I would do this there as the user could have their date set to 01/01/1970 and would see `2003-1970`.

Comment: You might want to do some research into copyright law to see whether that's necessary at all. (Personally I think it is not.)  Look up, in particular, the Berne Convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put `year` in quotes, it's a variable.  Putting it quotes makes the string `'year'`.

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear();  // This should be `new Date`
                                      // as `getFullYear` isn't a global function
$(document).ready (function(){
   $('div.footer').html($('div.footer').html() .replace('2011', year));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
getFullYear();
```

Should be:

```
new Date().getFullYear();
```

And, as pointed out by the other answers, the string `"year"` should be a variable `year`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remopve the quotes from 'year' so it's a variable. Otherwise, it's a string...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('div.footer').html($('div.footer').html() .replace('2011',year));
```

Since `year` is a  variable you should not put quotes around it.

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing 2011 with the string `'year'` not with the value of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> document.write(new Date().getFullYear()) </script>
```

One Liners are always effective in real life as well as Coding. To keep it simple and sweet just this one line of code.
As script takes javascript as default again declaring it not needed.

In this context You can add that one line of code after 2003- "add line of code here"
P.S. Works with all the major browsers and all browsers enabled with javascript(which mostly are).